# calculate percentage increase in powerpivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerbi

This is my table

Company----Year----price

A----------2001----50

A----------2002----75

B----------2001----15

I want to calculate % price increase in additional column using following formula

%chg for A in 2002=(75-50)/50

So my new table will look like this
Company----Year----price---%chg

A----------2001----50------0

A----------2002----75------**0.5**

B----------2001----15-----

Since I'm new to powerpivot and DAX, I do not know how to use filter functions to do this.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because Power BI is not ideal for iterative calculations. Please be aware, that the suggested solution might cause performance issues on big data sets:

First create a new column called `PriorYear`:

```
=CALCULATE(Max([Year]),FILTER(Table1,EARLIER([year]) > [year] && EARLIER([Company]) = [Company]))
```

After that create a column called `PriorPrice`:

```
=CALCULATE(Max([price]),Filter(Table1,EARLIER([PriorYear]) = [Year] && EARLIER([Company]) = [Company]))
```

And finally create a column called PriceRatio:

```
=IFERROR([price]/[PriorPrice]-1,0)
```

**Explanation:** `Earlier()` is a poorly chosen name for this function because it pretty much works like `ThisRowsValue()`. You need the `Max([price])`, because you can't evaluate on a column. You need to apply some arithmetic to it. Since there is only going to be one matching value the arithmetic could be everything (Also `Min()` or `Sum()`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. If Power BI is not ideal for iterative calculations, what would be ideal?.

Comment: To be 100% precise: Power BI is a good tool for this kind of analysis, but  the correct way to do it would be to work with measures. You would need to define your year as a proper date and create a "LastYearPrice" measure using the `DATEADD()` function. This would allow you to build the desired PriceRatio measure. This approach requires a bit more work and expertise than the one mentioned. Maybe this helps: http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2014/01/defanging-the-contiguous-date-selections-error/

Comment: Thankyou :). I look into it. 

Could you please check this post and help me on that. That would be my next step with the data.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246651/sorting-portfolios-based-on-criterias