# How to filter rows in a table based on values in another table in power query

Tags: filter, powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables in power query.

Price table

```
Date       Company  Price
01/01/2000  A        10
01/02/2000  A        12
01/03/2000  A        15
01/01/2000  B        15
01/02/2000  B        85
01/03/2000  B        98
```

Size table

```
 Date      Company  Size
01/06/2000  A        10
01/06/2001  A        12
01/06/2002  A        15
01/06/2000  B        15
01/06/2001  B        85
01/06/2002  B        98
```

In Price table, I want only to have companies which are in size table. In other words, If company C is not in the size table, I do not need that company data points in the price table. Here no need to consider the date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Power Query you can use the `Merge Queries` function to achieve that. (In the `Home --> Combine` section of the ribbon.

Select the `Join Kind` to determine which rows to keep.

In your example, create a query from the 2nd table and apply the following steps:

- Remove the date and the size column
- Remove duplicates

Afterwards you can join the first table with the newly created query and do a inner join. (Only keep matching entries)

Comment: My second table has data points as of June. But the first table has monthly data points. I want to achieve those companies which have included in the second table, only present in the first table. when I merge, will I get the same result?

Comment: I edited the answer, now it should be working for you.